# Cloning a cloud hosted database to local database

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I would like to clone a cloud-based postgresql database to a local databse.  I am using Datagrip.  I know I can just run a query and export the data as CSV and then create a local database and insert it.

Problem is:  the database has 155 fields and I want to avoid hardcode all theses fields to create a new database.

Is there a way to fast do it?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use `pg_dump` ?

Comment: I cant find this option in datagrip. Tried everything. I am not exp'ed with databases.  I just need to get the create the same table as I already have the csv.

Answer (score 0):

please read about [Export capabilities](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/export-data.html) in DataGrip
and also you can copy a table into another database using '[Copy Table](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/tables-copy.html)' feature.